# evaluating environment variable from file in csh

Tags: csh

I have a config file that contains the following line:

```
pre_args='$REGION','xyz',3
```

Using `perl` from within a csh script I can evaluate environment variable `$REGION` like so:

```
set pre_args = `grep -v '^#' $config_file | grep pre_args | cut -f 2 -d = | sed 's/ //g'`
if ("$pre_args" != "") then
   set pre_args = `echo $pre_args | perl -ne 'use Env; s/(\$\w+)/$1/eeg; print'`
endif
```

If `$REGION = SOUTH`, `$pre_args` is now set to: `SOUTH`,`xyz`,`3`.

Is there a way to do this using the shell's built-in commands and not having to rely on using `perl`? By the way, the choice to use `csh` is not mine, so please no replies criticizing that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `eval`, which parses and executes its arguments in the context of the current shell - something like this may work:

```
eval set pre_args = $pre_args
```

**Edit:** good point re. the quotes - thinking about it I'm surprised it evaluated the variable at all. Combining eval with an extra sed (to escape the quotes) seems to work here, but it's ugly:

```
set pre_args = grep -v '^#' config | grep pre_args | cut -f 2 -d = | sed 's/ //g' | sed "s/'/\\'/g"
set REGION = SOUTH
eval set pre_args = $pre_args
echo $pre_args
```

gives me `'SOUTH','xyz',3`

Comment: If I do that twice I'm halfway there, however, I loose the single quotes: SOUTH,xyz,3